# Is it possible for Docusaurus to work with styled-components?

Tags: styled-components, docusaurus, css-in-js

Docs for the possibility of styling components by css-in-js libraries are empty

https://docusaurus.io/docs/styling-layout#css-in-js

Comment: Consider that you've already decided to use a doc-generator like Docusaurus, which means you've implicitly agreed to trade-away customization and flexibility in exchange for having something _turnkey_. If you're not willing to yield _precise control_ over how styling works then you should look at generating your own docs from source.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Dai. I'm wondering if I could use Docusaurus only to generate "Docs" page and to use React + SC + Next.js for my landing page. The only thing that bothers me is whether it would be possible to make seamless navigation between Docusaurus and Next.js sites. Do you know if that's possible and do you think that it would be a good idea?